# Beautiful Soup not working on this website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape the URLs of all the items in the table but when I try, nothing comes up. The code is quite basic so I can see why it might not work. However, even trying to scrape the title of this website, nothing comes up. I at least expected the h1 tag as it's outside the table...

Website: https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/en/overview

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


lists =[]
url = 'https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/en/overview'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find_all('h1', class_='heading2 gbs-font-vanguard-red')
for links in soup.find_all('a', style='padding-bottom: 1px;'):
    link_text = links['href']
    lists.append(link_text)

print(title)
print(lists)
```

Comment: the most common problem - this page uses `JavaScript` to add elements but `requests`/ `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`. You may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`

Comment: Or you may try to use `DevTools` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` (tab `Network`, filter`XHR`) to find url used by JavaScript to get data - and use this url in `requests`. `JavaScript` may get data as `JSON` so it may no need to use `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always more efficient to get the data from the source as opposed to doing it through Selenium. Looks like the links are created through the portId.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


url = 'https://www3.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/funds.json'
payload = {
'context': '/personal/products/',
'countryCode': 'au.ret',
'paths': "[[['funds','legacyFunds'],'AU']]",
'method': 'get'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

results = jsonData['jsonGraph']['funds']['AU']['value']


df1 = pd.json_normalize(results, record_path=['children'])
df2 = pd.json_normalize(results, record_path=['listings'])


df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
df['url_link'] = 'https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/en/detail/' + df['portId'] + '/Overview'
```

**Output:**

```
print(df[['fundName', 'url_link']])
                                             fundName                                           url_link
0         Vanguard Active Emerging Market Equity Fund  https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/...
1             Vanguard Active Global Credit Bond Fund  https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/...
2                  Vanguard Active Global Growth Fund  https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/...
3   Vanguard Australian Corporate Fixed Interest I...  https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/...
4       Vanguard Australian Fixed Interest Index Fund  https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/...
..                                                ...                                                ...
23  Vanguard MSCI Australian Small Companies Index...  https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/...
24  Vanguard MSCI Index International Shares (Hedg...  https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/...
25       Vanguard MSCI Index International Shares ETF  https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/...
26  Vanguard MSCI International Small Companies In...  https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/...
27  Vanguard International Credit Securities Hedge...  https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/...

[66 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is caused by the JavaScript eventlistener, I would suggest you use `beautifulsoup` along with `selenium` to scrape this website. So, let's apply selenium at sending request and get back page source and then use `beautifulsoup` to parse it.

In addition, you should use  `title = soup.find()` instead of `title = soup.findall()` in order to get only one title.

The example of code using Firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/en/overview'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
browser.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
browser.close()

lists =[]
title = soup.find('h1', class_='heading2 gbs-font-vanguard-red')
for links in soup.find_all('a', style='padding-bottom: 1px;'):
    link_text = links['href']
    lists.append(link_text)

print(title)
print(lists)
```

Output:

```
<h1 class="heading2 gbs-font-vanguard-red">Investment products</h1>
['/personal/products/en/detail/8132', '/personal/products/en/detail/8219', '/personal/products/en/detail/8121',...,'/personal/products/en/detail/8217']
```

Comment: I get an error: Could not get version for google-chrome with the command... Current google-chrome version is UNKNOWN
Get LATEST chromedriver version for UNKNOWN google-chrome

Comment: Have you downloaded the ChromeDriver yet? or you use `webdriver manager` as the same as me?

Comment: Have you tried this one? `from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager`

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

Comment: I've updated my code to this and it doesn't work still:
`from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/en/overview'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get(url)`

Comment: From your code, you are still using `webdriver.Firefox()`.

Comment: `browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())` use this instead.

Comment: @turtle69 `ChromeDriverManager()` is only for `Chrome()`

Answer (score 2):

The most common problem (with many modern pages): this page uses `JavaScript` to add elements but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`.

You may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`.

---

This example use only Selenium without `BeautifulSoup`

I use `xpath` but you may also use `css selector`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
             
url = 'https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/en/overview'

lists = []

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedrive.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/path/to/geckodrive.exe")
driver.get(url)

title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h1[@class="heading2 gbs-font-vanguard-red"]')
print(title.text)

all_items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@style="padding-bottom: 1px;"]')

for links in all_items:
    link_text = links.get_attribute('href')
    print(link_text)
    lists.append(link_text)
```

---

- [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) (for Chrome)
- [GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.30.0) (for Firefox)

Comment: I get an error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: You have to add `/full/path/to/chromedrive.exe` to Chrome(), or you have to add folder with `chromedrive.exe` to system variable `PATH`. On linux I have folder `~/bin` on `PATH` and keep all executable in this file and I don't have to add this in `Chrome()`/`Firefox()`